# left hand operand has no effect warning when using for loop in C

Tags: c

I created a for loop and followed the guidelines for ","s and ";"s like such

```
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 10, j < 10; i++, j++) {
    //do something;
}
```

However I still got a warning when compiling saying that "left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect".

Comment: `i < 10` in `i < 10, j < 10` has no effect.

Comment: Which ide are you using?

Comment: Warnings are great to use a search query. Closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

`i < 10, j < 10`

is allowed but probably isn't what was intended as it discards the result of the first expression and returns the result of j < 10 only. The [Comma Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator) evaluates the expression on the left of the comma, discards it then evaluates the expression on the right and returns it. 
(Collected) https://stackoverflow.com/a/17638765/5610655

If you want to test for multiple conditions use the logical AND operator && instead. Btw, comma-separated conditions run fine in my IDE.

Similar concepts have also been discussed previously. Have a look.
[C++: Multiple exit conditions in for loop (multiple variables): AND -ed or OR -ed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18063552/5610655) 
[Are multiple conditions allowed in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17638730/5610655)

Here's a practical example. If you run the code given below, you'll see that it is outputting 10 times than 2 times

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main() 
    {
       int i,j;
       for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 2, j < 10; i++, j++) {
           printf("Hello, World!");
    }
}
--output----
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```

If you want both conditions to be effective, use AND(&&) operator instead of the comma-separated condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
    {
        int i,j;
       for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 2 && j < 10; i++, j++) {
           printf("Hello, World!\n");
    }
}
---output--
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```

It's unnecessary to use AND separated multiple conditions, only one will condition will suffice. The condition with fewer iteration steps will only be executed and the loop will break.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
    {
        int i,j;
       for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 2; i++, j++) {
           printf("Hello, World!\n");
    }
}
---output--
Hello, World!
Hello, World!
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved as pointed out by comments: "`&&`" instead of "`,`" must be used between "`i < 10`" and "`j < 10`"

```
for (i = 0, j = 0; i < 10 && j < 10; i++, j++) {
    //do something;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that a "double iterator" like this is really pointless unless `i` and `j` diverge in some meaningful way. In any case, do try and declare your loop variables within the loop scope, like `for (int i = 0, j = 0; ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

the use of values in `(i = 0, j = 0; i < 10, j < 10; i++, j++)` is useless in the sense that both `i` and `j` will reach the same values at the same time. Unless one of the values may change at a time not within the declaration of the for loop, this can be simplified to `(i = 0; i < 10; i++)`

Also, as others have pointed out, the comma separating the comparisons (although valid) should be replaced with a `&&`. In the end, the loop should either be

```
for ( i = 0, j = 0; i < 10 && j < 10; i++, j++ )
```

or

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
```

Although you should prefer the latter as the former makes use of unnecessary code.